# wpf mvvm threading.Timer and TimerCallback problems

Tags: wpf, mvvm, timer, callback, collectionviewsource

I have a WPF application developed against the MVVM framework in which the ViewModel constructor set a Timer with a TimerCallback.

The TimerCallback retrieves an ObservableCollection and passes it to a field on the VM.

I have a CollectionViewSource which has its Source property set to the ObservableCollection.  I am using a CollectionViewSource because I want to enable filtering on the Collection.

I have found that when the TimerCallback attempts to pass the ObservableCollection into the local field the Source property for the CollectionViewSource has an exception {"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."}.

I understand the exception but I have two problems:

1. How to get around this problem?
2. And more importantly why do I only get this issue when using a CollectionViewSource?  If I remove the CollectionViewSource and make the ObservableCollection a public property then I get no such exception.

Any help appreciated!  Thanks,
Drammy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the `DispatcherTimer` instead of the timer class you are using now, and make sure you create it on the UI thread.
2. Probably with just an `ObservableCollection` your UI is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

To partially answer your question, any updates on ObservableCollection that might be observed by UI elements must be dispatched through the UI thread.  When I wish to do this in MVVM, my strategy is to inject a SynchronizationContext into the constructor of the ViewModel that I initialize during my application startup.  This gives me a View-framework-independent way to dispatch updates that must be synchronized with the View.

Comment: (psst, DispatcherSynchronizationContext)

Comment: SynchronizationContext.Current will retrieve the synchronization context for the current application, if accessed from the UI thread; presumably this will be a DispatcherSynchronizationContext in WPF.